# DD_belatedPNG images disappear after document ready

Tags: internet-explorer-6, png

I'm using DD_belatedPNG to fix transparent PNGs in IE6; at a certain point I noticed that all fixed PNGs started disappearing a second after the document loaded. Something along these lines: page loads, 1 second passes, the transparency becomes viewable and the PNGs almost immediately disappear. Any clue on what the cause is and how to fix? Thanks!

UPDATE: the elements are still in place, so if one of the PNGs was a link, it is still clickable.

```
<script src="/scripts/plugins/DD_belatedPNG_0.0.7a-min.js"></script>
<script>
    PNG_selectors = ".bbb, #logo, #home_title, .home-image, ..........";
    alert("PNGs are going to disappear now");
    DD_belatedPNG.fix(PNG_selectors);
</script>
```

As long as the alert is in place they are there, once OK is clicked, they are gone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those who are interested, this was being caused by as script loading stuff from fonts.com... I set it to defer, and it fixed the issue. Sweet!

Comment: Be sure to accept your own answer. A little favor to others too.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try calling `DD_belatedPNG.fix()` only when the page has finished loading, then see if the problem goes away? Attach an event handler to `window.onload` like so:

```
<script>
window.onload = function() {
    var PNG_selectors = ".bbb, #logo, #home_title, .home-image, ..........";
    alert("PNGs are going to disappear now");
    DD_belatedPNG.fix(PNG_selectors);
};
</script>
```